# Create many files with random content

Tags: shell-script, files

I am looking for a command to create multiple (thousands of) files containing at least 1KB of random data.

For example,

```
Name            size
file1.01        2K
file2.02        3K
file3.03        5K
etc.
```

How can I create many files like this?

Comment: What did you mean by “exclusive”? It doesn't make sense in context, so you probably used the wrong word.

Comment: I meant that files can not have the same content.

Comment: So, exclusive would have meant unique.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since you don't have any other requirements, something like this should work:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
for n in {1..1000}; do
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=file$( printf %03d "$n" ).bin bs=1 count=$(( RANDOM + 1024 ))
done
```

(this needs `bash` at least for `{1..1000}`).

Comment: This needs `bash` for numerous reasons, including `$((…))` and `$RANDOM`.  Even `$(…)` might not exist in *every* shell.

Comment: @G-Man, in any case, none of those features are specific to `bash` nor did they originate in `bash`  (`{1..1000}` comes from `zsh`, `for n in...; done` and variable expansion comes from the Bourne shell, `$(...)`, `$((...))` and `$RANDOM`  come ksh). The features that are not POSIX are `{1..1000}`, `$RANDOM` and `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: If you wanted 1..1000 to be constant-width you need **`"%04d"`** in which case `bash` or `zsh` can do `{0001..1000}` with no `printf`

Comment: Additional feature: I need a way to spread these files over lots of randomly named nested subdirectories.

Answer (score 15):

A variation with `seq`, `xargs`, `dd` and `shuf`:

```
seq -w 1 10 | xargs -n1 -I% sh -c 'dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.% bs=$(shuf -i1-10 -n1) count=1024'
```

Explanation as requested per comments:

`seq -w 1 10` prints a sequence of numbers from *01* to *10*

`xargs -n1 -I%` executes the command `sh -c 'dd ... % ...'` for each sequence number replacing the *%* with it

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.% bs=$(shuf ...) count=1024` creates the files feeded from */dev/urandom* with *1024* blocks with a blocksize of

`shuf -i1-10 -n1` a random value from *1* to *10*

Comment: Wat does this exactly do?

Comment: @saru95 explanation added.

Comment: This creates 10 files with random size. Change "10" to the number of files wanted.

Answer (score 7):

This uses a single pipeline and seems fairly fast, but has the limitation that all of the files are the same size

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=10240 | split -a 4 -b 1k - file.
```

Explanation:
Use dd to create 10240*1024 bytes of data;
split that into 10240 separate files of 1k each (names will run from 'file.aaaa' through 'file.zzzz')

Answer (score 5):

This will create 15 files each contains 1MB of random data:

```
for i in {001..015}; do head -c 1M </dev/urandom >randfile$i; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
filecount=0
while [ $filecount -lt 10000 ] ; do
    filesize=$RANDOM
    filesize=$(($filesize+1024))
    base64 /dev/urandom | 
    head -c "$filesize" > /tmp/file${filecount}.$RANDOM
    ((filecount++))
done
```

Comment: I tried doing this but not worked. You might want to explain the parameters. :)

Comment: very fast thx @rahul

Answer (score 1):

Similar to lcd047's answer (it works with bash, even git bash on Windows), with the addition that the names are also randomized and of 1MB in size (might be more efficient disk-wise):

```
#! /bin/bash
s=$(hostname).$(pwd).${RANDOM}
for n in {1..1000}; do
    x=$( printf %04d "$n" )
    dd if=/dev/urandom of=$(echo "${x}.$(date +%s).${s}" | sha256sum -z | awk '{print $1}')$( printf %03d "$n" ).bin bs=1 count=1048576
done
```